# How to ignore lower or upper case letter?

Tags: java, scala

I have some function that checks for me inside a map if there are some combination of words:

```
val givenAddress = "something that is an address"
val answer = airportNameMap.filterKeys(_.split("").forall(givenAddress.contains))
```

The problem is that if the address is capital letters its not checking it....

What do I need to add to make sure it doesn't matter if the address is capital or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the given address as lower case like so:

```
val givenAddress = "SoMeThInG";
val answer = airportNameMap.filterKeys(_.split("").forall(givenAddress.toLowerCase().contains))
```

It will check the givenAddress as "something" instead of "SoMeThInG".

Answer (score 1):

Add .ToLower() or .ToUpper() to both the search expression and the field being searched.

Comment: I think scala is .toUpperCase()

Comment: Thank you I thought I was looking at c# questions.  Will be more careful.